# Reshape data in R using dcast

Tags: r, dcast

I have the following data

```
library(reshape2)

d <- data_frame(
            Quart = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q1","Q4","Q1", "Q2", "Q3"),
            var1 = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,2,3,0,1),
            var2= c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0),
            location= c("loc1", "loc1", "loc2", "loc2", "loc2", "loc2", "loc2",
                        "loc1", "loc2","loc1"))
```

I would like to reshape these data to create a table to look like the below.

The cell that is starred should be var1 multiplied by the number of loc1 where Quart=Q1. So in this scenario it would be '3',  loc2 would be '0' as there aren't any rows that have both Q1 and loc2, loc3 would be '1', and loc4 would be '0'.

[image]

I've tried to reshape the data using d cast:

```
  d%>%
  reshape2::dcast(formula = Quart * var1 ~ location
              ,fun.aggregate = length       
translates to counts
              ,margins = c("Quart", "var1")
  ) -> d
```

However this doesn't quite give me what I want. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to first use `tidyr::gather` to convert `var1` and `var2` in long format and then apply `dcast` as:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
gather(d, key, value, -Quart, -location) %>%
  dcast(Quart+key ~ location, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "value")

#   Quart  key loc1 loc2
# 1    Q1 var1    4    0
# 2    Q1 var2    1    0
# 3    Q2 var1    0    0
# 4    Q2 var2    0    1
# 5    Q3 var1    1    1
# 6    Q3 var2    0    1
# 7    Q4 var1    0    4
# 8    Q4 var2    0    3
```